# How set a new value to a struct field and return the old one in the mutable method in rust

Tags: rust

example:

```rust
struct Foo<V> {
    value: V,
}

impl<V> Foo<V> {
    fn insert(&mut self, value: V) -> Option<V> {
        // move occurs because `self.value` has type `V`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
        let v = self.value;
        self.value = value;

        Some(v)
    }
}
```

I know why rust complains about that, Is there an alternative to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`std::mem::replace`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.replace.html). It reads data from `dest` pointer, and places `src` in its place.

```rust
struct Foo<V> {
    value: V,
}

impl<V> Foo<V> {
    fn insert(&mut self, value: V) -> Option<V> {
        let v = std::mem::replace(&mut self.value, value);
        Some(v)
    }
}
```